# Posting a comment redirects admin/users to blank page

Tags: posts, comments

I have looked a lot on this problem on forums and tried out a few of the solutions but nothing seems to work for me.

When I try to comment here:
http://www.chicitout.co.nf/crochet-lace-skater-dress/

it redirects us to a blank page. I tried logged in as admin and also logged out.
I dont have Akismet activated.

Any suggestions?

Thanks, :)

Comment: Please add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to your **question** to make answers possible.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access your site via FTP or through your host control panels file manager?

If you can, check to see if there is any code within wp-comments-post.php in the root of your site.

If it is empty, paste this inside:

```
<?php
/**
 * Handles Comment Post to WordPress and prevents duplicate comment posting.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

if ( 'POST' != $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
    header('Allow: POST');
    header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    exit;
}

/** Sets up the WordPress Environment. */
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

nocache_headers();

$comment = wp_handle_comment_submission( wp_unslash( $_POST ) );
if ( is_wp_error( $comment ) ) {
    $data = $comment->get_error_data();
    if ( ! empty( $data ) ) {
        wp_die( $comment->get_error_message(), $data );
    } else {
        exit;
    }
}

$user = wp_get_current_user();

/**
 * Perform other actions when comment cookies are set.
 *
 * @since 3.4.0
 *
 * @param WP_Comment $comment Comment object.
 * @param WP_User    $user    User object. The user may not exist.
 */
do_action( 'set_comment_cookies', $comment, $user );

$location = empty( $_POST['redirect_to'] ) ? get_comment_link( $comment ) : $_POST['redirect_to'] . '#comment-' . $comment->comment_ID;

/**
 * Filter the location URI to send the commenter after posting.
 *
 * @since 2.0.5
 *
 * @param string     $location The 'redirect_to' URI sent via $_POST.
 * @param WP_Comment $comment  Comment object.
 */
$location = apply_filters( 'comment_post_redirect', $location, $comment );

wp_safe_redirect( $location );
exit;
?>
```